# PHP Mysqli prepared statement select fetch_assoc gives empty result

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying something very simple, but for some reason it won't work as I expected it would. For this I want to select a specific row and then assign the row to another table via update.

Here is the script I want to run:

```
<?php
$passedID = $_POST["upvotedurl"];

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'osscom_users_test');

$sqlstm = "SELECT * FROM image_uploads WHERE THMPATH=?";
$fstmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqlstm);
$fstmt->bind_param("s", $passedID);
$fstmt->execute();
$fstmt->store_result();
$json = $fstmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

foreach ($json as $value) {

    $val1 = $value['THMPATH']; // this is empty, why???

    $sql = "UPDATE image_uploads SET IMGNAME=? WHERE THMPATH=?";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $val1, $passedID);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
$fstmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

for a strange reason which I cannot explain the variable `$value` form the `SELECT` query is empty.

As you can see in the example I am getting the `THMPATH` which is definitely not empty and I'm also using the same value for the `UPDATE` below. If I would use something like `$val1 = "Wololo"` it would work without a problem.

Why is my `$value` (in this case `$value['THMPATH']`) empty? This makes no sense?

### Update

When running `file_put_contents('../session/log.txt', print_r($json, true));` this is the result:

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 511
    [OWNER] => User Name
    [IMGNAME] => Wagirigoingi
    [IMGTAGS] => image, photo, picture
    [IMGPATH] => 1028525690.jpg
    [THMPATH] => ../thumbnails/5560921208_username.jpg
    etc..
)
```

So the select worked, but I still cannot get the values.

Comment: its the result of `$fstmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();` the table itself has just a few members like `IMGPATH`, `IMGNAME` ect. And all of these values are to 100% not empty. But still I get an empty result, for all of them.. I'm also getting 1 row when I test it with `mysqli_num_rows()`, it just seems that I cannot get the values of that row..

Comment: the script runs in a separate file so it's pretty hard for me to get the print_r since I'm not using any IDE.. I'll try to get the output and then update my question..

Comment: ok, this worked! thank you very much for this tip. But as for the result of $json it is as I said. I've updated the question but there is exactly in $json what should be there.. I just cannot get the values out..

Comment: I'm not that fast. The update is there now. I probably should have said `I'm going to` instead ^^

Comment: I just used the code you gave me.. anyway, does it really matter? The structure should be correct, I've used this code in other places of my project too.. it has always worked out so far.. knowing the structure won't change that.

Comment: Ok here you go.. But as I said.. It won't change anything, it is all as it should be..

Comment: You can't use `store_result` and `get_result` at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is a single record in an array. When you do `foreach ($json as $value)`, `$value` will have 511, User Name, Wagirigoingi, etc. At some point, `$value` will have the value corresponding to THMPATH in the `$json` array, but at no time will `$value` be an array, so `$value['THMPATH']` is never going to be valid.

What you presumably want is to just eliminate the `foreach` loop entirely.

Comment: Sounds good, can you give me a code example, I'm struggling to understand how I need to write that.. and thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Exactly what you have, but remove the `foreach` line, and the `}` that closes that loop.

Comment: yeah, I got it now changed.. `$json` to `$value` and removed the loop. I see now how this works. Thank you so much, this was awesome help of you!

Comment: See how important the data structure is. :-)

Comment: Yes, I didn't realize until now that the other implementations I mentioned were also wrong and not working.. haha, my bad. Thanks for being so persistent :)